# Build OpenSSH client only

Tags: package-management, compiling, packaging, configure

I'm trying to build [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) 7.9p1 from source, but I can't find a way to delete (or not include), for instance, `ssh-agent`, `ssh-keygen`, `scp`, `sftp`, `sshd`, etc. – of course, assuming none of those are required for the `ssh` command to work.

Ideally I would only need the client: the `ssh` command, but again, I'm not sure what other pieces are required. I think most of what's build/installed is used by the server, not by the client.

Comment: Please tell us *why* you need a special openssh-client: 1. Are you running or creating a linux distro? Please tell us about your operating system. 2. Are you creating some 'fool-proof' system with client computers, that can only run a few necessary programs, and one of them is `ssh`, but not transfer files, so you want to remove `sftp` and `scp` ? 3. Or something else?

Comment: I have to build it from source, it's to make a Flatpak, and the SSH client is a dependency. I don't want to shovel everything-SSH there if it's not needed. I was going the route @JeffSchaller proposed but I first wanted to know if there was another way. I can identify the location(s) where the other (potentially) unneeded files are "installed" and remove them, but like I said I would like to avoid that if there is a way to tell `configure` to not consider some "packages", etc. For instance, the `openssh-client` from Ubuntu would be perfect for me case, but I can't use a `.deb` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the default build system provided.

If you look at the `Makefile` that is generated by running the provided `./configure` script, you should see that the default (first) target is

```
TARGETS=ssh$(EXEEXT) sshd$(EXEEXT) ssh-add$(EXEEXT) ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT) ssh-keyscan${EXEEXT} ssh-keysign${EXEEXT} ssh-pkcs11-helper$(EXEEXT) ssh-agent$(EXEEXT) scp$(EXEEXT) sftp-server$(EXEEXT) sftp$(EXEEXT)
```

(for Unix-like systems, `$(EXEEXT)` should be empty). Each has its own separate build target / rule so for example you can do:

```
make ssh
```

to make only the client.

Ex.

```
$ make ssh

<snip>

$ find . -type f -executable -newermt yesterday
./config.status
./ssh

$ ./ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Comment: Great, let me try that first and I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the info!